# Postman sendRequest with predefined request from collection

Tags: postman

is it possible to use pm.sendRequest() and put a name of predefined request from collection or variable that stores it, instead of typing whole url and all headers etc. ?
I know how to use setNextRequest(), but with that I have to type much more logic and operate on splicing array instead of simple forEach (regards to the topic request that needs an 'id' as an path param).